# Muestra Fecha Formato diferente SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

Hola Tengo una Tabla que tiene una columna Fecha, esta tiene tres formatos de fecha (04/10/2018) (2018-10-04) (20181004), lo que me gustaría hacer es en una consulta poder igualar el formato de las tres.
Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar una aclaración para otros que lean esto, lo que se tiene es una cadena que representa una fecha, las fechas en sí no tienen formato. En dicha cadena por lo que dices tienes 3 formatos distintos

```
04/10/2018
2018-10-04
20181004
```

Que coinciden con tres formatos distintos que maneja la función [`CONVERT()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) lo único que correspondería es verificar de antemano cual de ellos es, viendo si tiene guiones, barras o nada:

```
SELECT  F.FechaString,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', F.FechaString) > 0 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, F.FechaString, 103) -- British
         WHEN CHARINDEX('-', F.FechaString) > 0 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, F.FechaString, 111) -- Japan
         ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, F.FechaString, 112)                                        -- ISO
    END
    FROM (  SELECT '04/10/2018' AS FechaString UNION
            SELECT '2018-10-04' UNION
            SELECT '20181004'
    ) F
```

Salida:

```
╔═════════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║ FechaString ║                          ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║ 04/10/2018  ║ 04/10/2018 12:00:00 a.m. ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║ 2018-10-04  ║ 04/10/2018 12:00:00 a.m. ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║ 20181004    ║ 04/10/2018 12:00:00 a.m. ║
╚═════════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

En caso que tuvieras SQL 2012 o superior, puede ser conveniente reemplazar [`CONVERT()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) por [`TRY_CONVERT()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), la primera generará una excepción/error si no logra convertir la cadena a la fecha, la segunda no (pero retorna NULL), por lo que podría servirte si eventualmente tienes más formatos de los que has mencionado.

Comment: Funciona perfecto muchas gracias